# Categorization & Validity of a clause

Tags: phrases, participles

if I have the sentence "A killing B is called murder." is "A killing B" a regular participle clause or is that impossible because it has a subject?

In other words: Can a participle clause have a subject (- noun phrase)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can, is the short answer.

Most non-finite clauses are subjectless, but there are some that do have subjects, including participial clauses:

*She insisted on [me/my being present at the birth].*

*He sought advice from Ed, [he/him being the most knowledgeable of the group].*

And your example, as well as others like it, does too:

*[A killing B] is called murder*.

*Kim hated [him playing golf every day].*

*[His old car being written off], he was forced to buy a new one.*